# How to zip a .txt file and a folder in a single zip file using windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip

How to zip multiple file to a specific zip file name? I am using winzip 32.

Folder structure

```
C:\Documents\record.txt
C:\Documents\BlobFiles\abcd.pdf
```

Now I want to zip record.txt and BlobFiles folder to a single zip file named record.zip
Under the navigation of C:\Documents

Output should look like

```
C:\Documents\record.txt
C:\Documents\BlobFiles\abcd.pdf
C:\Documents\record.zip
```

I am using the below script

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\winzip32.exe" -a "C:\Documents\record.zip" "C:\Documents\"
```

Wanted to zip everything that is under `C:\Documents` to a single zip file.

What are the ways to achieve this ?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to use the [Winzip command line client](https://www.winzip.com/win/en/downcl.html). This gives you much more fexibility.

Comment: actually I don't have the privilege to install new zip, I am using client machine.

Comment: It is a free addon for Winzip.  I have never understood why they do not include it when you purchase and install Winzip.  But to answer your question, a simple Google search and you could have found a nice article on what the command line options are for Winzip32.exe.  The option you are looking for is `-r`.

Comment: Another option is `7zip`, with its command line version `7z.exe` - no install needed.

Comment: You willing to use a powershell hybrid script?

Comment: actually I have used windows batch script at all other places, so was hoping to use the same here also.

Comment: I've used 7-zip for this kind of job.  They provide a standalone executable `7za.exe` for exactly this purpose.  Here's a [comparison between 7z.exe and 7za.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/1105516/comparing-7z-exe-and-7za-exe)

Comment: Can you please tell me how 7-zip would work in my case ? to zip a file and a folder? with no installation needed..

Comment: @shivam did you not read my last comment? All you have to do is use the -r option to make the command recursive.